# Twitterで他人のリツイートを検索する方法

Tags: python, twitter, webapi

from:ユーザー名 filter:nativeretweets

この検索コマンドで検索するとユーザーがリツイートしたツイートが出るのですが、URLを出すとそのユーザーがリツイートしたという情報が追加されます。(RT@(ユーザー名)が先頭についたものになる)
URLでユーザーがリツイートしたツイートのみを表示するには検索コマンドに何を追加すればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: 「Twitter apiの検索コマンド」が何を指しているのかよくわかりませんでした。どういった回答を想定して質問されているのでしょうか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます 質問を編集しました

Comment: "URLを出す" も "そのユーザーがリツイートしたという情報が追加されます" も不明ですね。コードがあるならコードを、結果があるなら結果を書きましょう。肝心な部分が日本語では分からないです。"RT@(ユーザー名)が先頭についたものになる"も同様で、ツイートのJSONからtextを取り出したものの話をしているんだろうなと想像できますが、それが合っているかわかりません。

Comment: "URLでユーザーがリツイートしたツイートのみ" の係り受けも分からないですね。

Answer (score 1):

[Standard search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets)を使用した場合、[Tweet Object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object)の配列が返されます。

`from:ユーザー名 filter:nativeretweets` でリツイートのみを検索しているので、`ユーザー名`のTweet Objectとして返されますが、`retweeted_status`が含まれる仕様です。これこそが「ユーザーがリツイートしたツイート」を指していますので、ここから、`id_str`や`user.id_str`を参照することでURLを構築することができるかと思います。

なお、Standard search APIは`since_id`（`since_id_str`）が返されるので、検索結果の続きを参照することができます。（7日しか返ってこないなんてことはないと思いたいです…）

Answer (score 0):

REST APIの[statuses/user_timeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline)エンドポイントを使うと、ユーザのツイートのうち最新の3200件を取得できます。APIレスポンスとして返ってくるJSONの、それぞれのツイートに含まれる`retweeted`キーを見ると、そのツイートがリツイートか否か[判断できる](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object)ので、これを使って分類できると思います。

[search/tweets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets)エンドポイントでも[簡易なフィルタ](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators)でリツイートだけを選び出せそうですが、検索範囲が7日以内のツイートに限られるのが微妙です。

参考：[PythonでTwitter APIを使いたい！](https://qiita.com/h_tashiro/items/ed119c237f5595c3d7b8)